# Problema usando json_decode() (Array to string conversion) php

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de usar json_decode() de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
//Este es el json
$fol ='[{"name":"Taili Silva","screen_name":"taili_silva","id":837254166619770880,"id_str":"837254166619770880","connections":["following","followed_by"]}]';

$str =json_decode($fol, TRUE);

echo $str['connections'];
?>
```

y este es el error :

> Notice: Array to string conversion in line 3

Me podrían dar alguna explicación o solución

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El aviso

> Array to string conversion

viene dado en este caso porque estás tratando de imprimir con `echo` un array, lo cual es imposible.

Si quieres imprimir el array sólo para verificar lo que hay dentro de él, puedes usar `print_r`, `var_dump` o `var_export`.

Si necesitas guardarlo en una variable o imprimirlo con `echo` tienes que recorrer el array en un bucle y recuperar sus valores.

Además, en los datos que tienes, `connections` es a su vez un array:

```
        ...    [connections] => Array
                (
                    [0] => following
                    [1] => followed_by
                ) ...
```

Por lo tanto, es imposible acceder a sus valores de forma directa como lo estás haciendo. Si de todos modos no quieres usar bucles, puedes acceder a cada valor de esta forma nada elegante y poco práctica, sobre todo en arrays con muchos valores:

```
echo $arr[0]["connections"][0];
```

Imprime:

```
following
```

Y

```
echo $arr[0]["connections"][1];
```

Imprime:

```
followed_by
```

Veamos:

```
<?php

$fol='[{
    "name": "Taili Silva",
    "screen_name": "taili_silva",
    "id": 837254166619770880,
    "id_str": "837254166619770880",
    "connections": ["following", "followed_by"]
}]';


$arr =json_decode($fol, TRUE);

echo "VER ARRAY COMPLETO:\n\n";
print_r($arr);

echo "\n\nBUSCAR CONNECTIONS EN ARRAY:\n";


foreach ($arr as $row)
{
    $arrConnections=$row["connections"]; //Es un array
}

echo "\n\nCONNECTIONS ES A SU VEZ UN ARRAY:\n";


print_r($arrConnections);

echo "\n\nVER VALORES EN ARRAY CONNECTIONS:\n";


foreach ($arrConnections as $row)
{
    echo $row."\n"; //Aquí podemos usar los valores como variables o usar echo
}


?>
```

### Resultado:

```
--VER ARRAY COMPLETO:

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Taili Silva
            [screen_name] => taili_silva
            [id] => 837254166619770880
            [id_str] => 837254166619770880
            [connections] => Array
                (
                    [0] => following
                    [1] => followed_by
                )

        )

)


--BUSCAR CONNECTIONS EN ARRAY:    
--CONNECTIONS ES A SU VEZ UN ARRAY:

Array
(
    [0] => following
    [1] => followed_by
)


--VER VALORES EN ARRAY CONNECTIONS:

following
followed_by
```

---

Además, tu JSON tiene otra situación suplementaria, y es que, al estar entre `[]` se trata de un array JSON, que no es lo mismo que un objeto JSON, pues estos últimos están encerrados entre `{}`.

Si tú quieres acceder directamente a una propiedad del array tienes entonces que poner el índice delante.

Por ejemplo:

```
print_r($arr[0]["connections"]);
```

Dará como resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => following
    [1] => followed_by
)
```

Si fuera un objeto JSON (sin `[]`):

```
$fol='{
    "name": "Taili Silva",
    "screen_name": "taili_silva",
    "id": 837254166619770880,
    "id_str": "837254166619770880",
    "connections": ["following", "followed_by"]
}';
```

Entonces podrías leerlo así:

```
print_r($arr["connections"]);
```

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => following
    [1] => followed_by
)
```

P.D.: Si interesa, más adelante completo un demo con más detalles.

Comment: Gracias por el dato esta muy completo

Answer (score 1):

Usa `var_dump($str);` para imprimir los arrays o `print_r($str);`

`echo` no imprime arrays

Comment: Lo se amigo pero no buscaba solo imprimir el resultado igual quería ocupar el resultado gracias y saludes